# Clique number and spectrum of a graph

Tags: reference-request, spectral-graph-theory

In the [Wikipedia article on Grassmann graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_graph) it is stated that in this graph:

$$\omega=1-\frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}$$

where $\omega$ is the clique number of the graph, and $\lambda_{max}$ and $\lambda_{min}$ are its maximum and minimum adjacency eigenvalues, respectively.

Now, I have two questions:

1. Where can I find the proof of this claim?
2. Is there any information about graphs for which this equality (or at least the inequality $\omega \geq 1-\frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}$) holds? For example, perfect graphs satisfy the latter inequality.

Comment: It is a policy on Wikipedia to include citations for non-trivial facts. Consider tagging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed